как отключить остановку кода при ошибке telebot python
у меня есть код для бота telegram, который должен решать уравнения он прекрасно работает, но если ввести в него не уравнение, то он прекращает работу, и код нужно запускать заново. как это исправить?
import json
from sympy import symbols, solve, parse_expr, simplify
from collections.abc import Mapping
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import standard_transformations, implicit_multiplication_application
tok= ''
bot = telebot.TeleBot(tok)


transformations = (standard_transformations + (implicit_multiplication_application,))


def add_user(message,name):
    file = open('id{}.json'.format(message.from_user.id), 'w')
    file.write(str(message))
    file.close()

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def intro(message):
    name =message.from_user.first_name
    str = f'Привет,{name} , этот бот решает уравнения и строит графикиヽ(´ー`)人(´∇｀)人(`Д´)ノ'
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, str)
    add_user(message,message.from_user.id)

def map_operations(formula_str):
    return formula_str.replace("^", "**").replace("=", "-")
def solving(formula):
    f = parse_expr(map_operations(formula), transformations=transformations)
    roots = solve(f)
    string = 'x='
    for el in roots:
        string += str(el)
        string += ';'
    return string

@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def handle_text(message):
    ur = str(message.text)
    root= solving(ur)
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id,root)
    print(ur, root)
@bot.message_handler(commands=['graph'])
def graph(message):
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Функция пока не работает T_T')
bot.polling(non_stop='True')```


Нужно сделать обработчик исключений, в рамках библиотеки telebot это делается так:
import telebot

tok = ''


class ExceptionHandler(telebot.ExceptionHandler):
    def handle(self, exception):
        print(exception)
        return True


bot = telebot.TeleBot(tok, exception_handler=ExceptionHandler()) 

Это также может быть полезным https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/discussions/1939
